# call procedures with output parameter from java

Tags: java, sql

I have this procedure and i want to call it from Java

```
declare 
    output number; 
begin 
    output := procedure_name(dateType => 'D', dateFrom => '20130825', dateTo => '20130830'); 
end;
```

I have used StoredProcedure and i have set the parameters for dateType, dateFrom and dateTo but my question is how do I retrieve the output parameter

This is what i have done so far:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedure_name");

    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("output",String.class , ParameterMode.OUT);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("dateType", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("dateFrom", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("dateTo", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);


    storedProcedure.setParameter("dateType", "YYYYMMDD");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("dateFrom", "20130825");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("dateTo", "20130830");

    storedProcedure.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You [call](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html#getOutputParameterValue-java.lang.String-) `storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("output")`.

Comment: when i do this i get an error like: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procedure_name'

Comment: @bla then check the arguments of the stored procedure... maybe the output is not a string, but a number as your code seems to indicate.

Comment: i get this error:  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults. Is it maybe because I need to rewrite the procedure in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call below code to get the same..

```
(String)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("output");
```

If above is throwing any error it means you are having issue with procedure

Comment: i get an  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults error

Comment: @blaa can you please provide complete stacktrace as well this error is coming before the above line or after the above line. As well it looks like stored procedure is not casting out parameter to String I think you need to look only in stored procedure.

Comment: @ prashant the error is coming from this line above